Ensure concurrency and avoid time overlapping in a reservation app made with Spring Boot and Hiberante
I am building a Java/Spring/Hibernate app that manages reservations of a tennis court.
Each user reserves time slots in which they will play.
Time slots are stored in a PostgreSQL database, with meaningful columns are reservation_start and reservation_end.
Time slots cannot overlap each other, as the court cannot be reserved from several users at same time.
When a user reserves the court, new record is created in the database following next algorithm:

Several interval duration checks. Do not allow intervals greater than 1 hour
Query intervals starting in same day of new interval being created and store in a variable.
Check that new interval does not overlap with step 2 intervals.
If everything is ok, insert new interval.

The problem here is the concurrency. Imagine that two users are trying to reserve same intervals at same time. Application will load existing intervals which will be stored in a variable. Just in that moment there is no problem, because none of the intervals are yet stored in the database, so all checks will pass and both overlapping reservations will be inserted.
The problem could be solved with triggers and/or checks at database level, but better to keep the business logic in Java code and not in the database.
I thought in next method:

Lock the entire table so just only one user can read existing reservations and insert its new. The problem I see here is the performance degradation. If many users are trying to reserve, just only one can do it at same time.

So, What do you think? How real-world reservation applications are implemented to solve concurrency and overlap problems?
Thanks.

Use a RANGE data type in combination with an exclusion constraint. See the manual for an example and all the details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT

but better to keep the business logic in Java code and not in the database. Good luck with that. The application has no idea about concurrency, you have to rebuild database functionality in your application. What a range type and a constraint can do within 5 minutes, will take you years to rebuild and test in your application. Or you have to sacrifice performance and lock the tables for every insert and update query.

As there rather a little possibility for conflicts you may use "optimistic locking" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

Related: Optimistic vs. Pessimistic locking and Hibernate/Spring : Pessimist vs Optimist locking?
